# How to extern from <algorithm> in Cython

Tags: python, c++, templates, stl, cython

I'm trying to use `partial_sort` from the `<algorithm>` library within Cython, but I just cannot find the correct way to properly `extern` it.

[reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/partial_sort/)

Here's my failed attempt:

```
%%cython -f

cdef extern from "<algorithm>" namespace "std":
    void partial_sort[RandomAccessIterator](RandomAccessIterator first, RandomAccessIterator middle, RandomAccessIterator last)
    void partial_sort[RandomAccessIterator, Compare](RandomAccessIterator first, RandomAccessIterator middle, RandomAccessIterator last, Compare comp)
```

Error message when using Cython 0.19.1:

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...

cdef extern from "<algorithm>" namespace "std":
    cdef cppclass RandomAccessIterator:
        cppclass Compare
        void partial_sort[RandomAccessIterator]
                                             ^
------------------------------------------------------------

/Users/richizy/.ipython/cython/_cython_magic_cf4fbe14563c3de19c8c3af3253a182e.pyx:5:46: Not allowed in a constant expression

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...

cdef extern from "<algorithm>" namespace "std":
    cdef cppclass RandomAccessIterator:
        cppclass Compare
        void partial_sort[RandomAccessIterator]
                                             ^
------------------------------------------------------------

/Users/richizy/.ipython/cython/_cython_magic_cf4fbe14563c3de19c8c3af3253a182e.pyx:5:46: Array dimension not integer

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...

cdef extern from "<algorithm>" namespace "std":
    cdef cppclass RandomAccessIterator:
        cppclass Compare
        void partial_sort[RandomAccessIterator]
                        ^
------------------------------------------------------------

/Users/richizy/.ipython/cython/_cython_magic_cf4fbe14563c3de19c8c3af3253a182e.pyx:5:25: Array element type 'void' is incomplete
```

Error message when using Cython 0.20.1:

```
CompileError: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

warning: .ipython/cython/_cython_magic_121a91d1fdd64d85c4b01e6540fd86d6.pyx:4:52: Function signature does not match previous declaration
```

---

Edit: As of 2/22/14, for Cython 0.20.1

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cython-users/H4UEM6IlvpM

> Correct, Cython does not support default template specializations (for
>   functions or classes). Nor does it support non-typename template 
>   parameters (with out some hacking).  Both are missing features that 
>   we'd like to get to someday.
>
> - Robert

Comment: Which version of Cython are you using ? Template function were not supported in Cython 0.19.1

Comment: Your first code works for me for with Cython 0.20 !

Comment: I was previously using 0.19.1. I've now updated to 0.20.1, but it throws me a CompileError along with "warning ... Function signature does not match previous declaration"

Comment: Please ask your question with a **complete and unique code**. There are four versions here and I don't know which one you are using.

Comment: I've updated the question to make it clear. There weren't 4 versions of the same code, as those were just what Cython prints as the error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that Cython doesn't work well with template specialization. The following code works for me (Cython version 0.20, Python 2.7.5, g++ (SUSE Linux) 4.8.1)

```
from libcpp.vector cimport vector

cdef extern from "<algorithm>" namespace "std":
    void partial_sort[RandomAccessIterator](RandomAccessIterator first, RandomAccessIterator middle, RandomAccessIterator last)
    #    void partial_sort[RandomAccessIterator, Compare](RandomAccessIterator first, RandomAccessIterator middle, RandomAccessIterator last, Compare comp)

cpdef bla():
    cdef vector[int] v
    cdef int i = 0
    cdef list res = []
    v.push_back(4)
    v.push_back(6)
    v.push_back(2)
    v.push_back(5)
    partial_sort[vector[int].iterator](v.begin(), v.end(), v.end())
    for i in v:
        res.append(i)
    return res
```

Then

```
>>> import bla
>>> bla.bla()
[2, 4, 5, 6]
```

However uncommenting the line break the code with

```
bla.pyx:15:16: Wrong number of template arguments: expected 2, got 1
```

Here is a workaround: You declare the different specialization of the template function under two different names:

```
cdef extern from "<algorithm>" namespace "std":
    void partial_sort_1 "std::partial_sort"[RandomAccessIterator](RandomAccessIterator first, RandomAccessIterator middle, RandomAccessIterator last)
    void partial_sort_2 "std::partial_sort"[RandomAccessIterator, Compare](RandomAccessIterator first, RandomAccessIterator middle, RandomAccessIterator last, Compare comp)
```

And then you use the correct one as in:

```
partial_sort_1[vector[int].iterator](v.begin(), v.end(), v.end())
```

**Note:** I got from [Cython-Users](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cython-users/H4UEM6IlvpM) that this is a know problem and that having template partial specialization on Cython is on their wish list for a moment.